# Extracting Information from a List of Documents

Tags: python, list, date

I have extracted a large number of .txt documents from folders (using glob). I have then appended each document into a list called MaxDoc by doing this:

```
Documents1 = glob.glob('path*.txt')

MaxDoc = []

for file in Documents1:
     f = open(file,'r')
     MaxDoc.append(f.readlines())
     f.close()
```

now, what I want to do is this: each item in that list is a whole document. each document has a section that says "Date of Last Revision: mm/dd/yyyy" and also "Revision No: xx"

here is a snapshot of what the part of the doc that has the info looks like:
[image]

I have been trying to see if I could iterate over the list and use regex to find the strings and extract the info. Once I extract it, I need to save it as a variable because I need to delete all the top portion of this document (the later portion of the doc is a table, and I want to convert that to a df). TIA for any advice!

EDIT:

I have used this regex pattern to test on just one of the text documents as below:

```
handle = open('path','r').read()

Date_of_Last_Rev = re.findall(r'Date\sOf\sLast\sRevision:\s(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)',handle)

Revision_No: = re.findall(r'Revision\sNo.:(\s\d\d)', handle, re.S)

output: Date_of_Last_Rev: ['12/27/2021'] 
output: Revision_No: ['18']
```

so the regex pattern works and it is able to identify the correct information. However, I still cannot get it to iterate over each document in the list MaxDoc.

I have tried this:

```
for item in MaxDoc:
     Date_of_Last_Rev = 
     re.findall(r'Date\sOf\sLast\sRevision:\s(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)',MaxDoc)

     Revision_No: = re.findall(r'Revision\sNo.:(\s\d\d)', MaxDoc, re.S)
```

and this:

```
for line, item in MaxDoc:
     Date_of_Last_Rev = 
     re.findall(r'Date\sOf\sLast\sRevision:\s(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)',MaxDoc)

     Revision_No: = re.findall(r'Revision\sNo.:(\s\d\d)', MaxDoc, re.S)
```

I either get an error: 'expected string or bytes-like object' (first example) or empty lists (second example)

As requested, here is an example of the text:

"REGISTER OF WAGE DETERMINATIONS UNDER  |        U.S. DEPARTMENT OF LABOR
THE SERVICE CONTRACT ACT        |  EMPLOYMENT STANDARDS ADMINISTRATION
By direction of the Secretary of Labor |         WAGE AND HOUR DIVISION
|         WASHINGTON D.C.  20210
|
|
|
| Wage Determination No.: 2015-4001
Daniel W. Simms          Division of   |           Revision No.: 18
Director            Wage Determinations|  Date Of Last Revision: 12/27/2021
***************************************|***************************************_____
Note: Contracts subject to the Service Contract Act are generally required to
pay at least the applicable minimum wage rate required under Executive Order
14026 or Executive Order 13658.

Comment: If you have been trying, what did not work?

Comment: @3DspatialUser, I defined a function RevDate(s), and did "return [i for i in f if re.search(r''Date\sof\sLast\sRevision:\s(\d\d\\\d\d\\\d\d\d\d)', i)]". then called the function on MaxDoc "Last_Rev_Date =  RevDate(MaxDoc). this created a list variable Last_Rev_Date, but it was empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just look for the key words and then extract only the content:

```
import re

txt = '''
This is a part text
With multi line

It could be a text 
document.
Revision No.: 18
Date: 12/27/2021

Other text

table,table,table
table,table,table
'''

results = re.findall(r'Revision No\.:\s*(\d+).*Date:\s*([\d\/]+)', txt, re.S)

for i in results:
    print('Revision:', i[0])
    print('Date:', i[1])
```

Comment: this gave me a list called 'results' and it was empty :(. I just can't seem to get it to find regex in the doc

Comment: Did you try my code or did you use my regex on your document? If it's the latter please give a doc example for me to try myself. Assuming about how everything might be formatted does not lead to a quick result...

Answer (score 0):

If each item in the list is the whole document ( I assume a string ) Then you can use regex with multistring.

I do not have your text (not given in the question) but I will show you an example with other text and you can use that as a start for your own code.

```py
import re

txt='''
This is a part text
With multi line

It could be a text 
document.
Revision No.: 18
Date: 12/27/2021

Other text

table,table,table
table,talbe,table
'''

reg_revision_no = re.compile(r'(Revision\sNo.:\s+\d+)')
reg_date = re.compile(r'(Date:\s+\d2\/\d{2}\/\d{4})')

files = [txt, txt]
for file in files:
    revision_no = reg_revision_no.search(file, re.M).group()
    date = reg_date.search(file, re.M).group()
    print(f"Revision No.: {revision_no}\nData: {date}")
```

output:

```
Revision No.: Revision No.: 18
Data: Date: 12/27/2021
Revision No.: Revision No.: 18
Data: Date: 12/27/2021
```

Comment: thanks, this is the direction I was trying to go in. However, I'm getting a "NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error. Is this because it's not finding the strings during the search? If so, maybe I need to just figure out the correct regex for it.

Comment: Yes that means that the regex is empty. You did not show what your data looks like so I cannot test it with your example, but I hope that this example works for you and that you can go further from there.